# Inheritance in Java. Questions at interview

Tags: java, inheritance

This question i was asked in the interview for Java programmer. Look at the code below. I need to make minimal changes to make this **a.f2();** works.

```
public class A {
  void f1(){}   
}

public class B extends A {
  void f2(){}
}

void main(String[] args) {
  A a =  ...     <- free space here
  a.f1();
}
```

**additional 1**
I've added void f2(){} to the class A, but have beed asked to make it in another way.

**additional 2**
No more free space wasnt in this code

> `enter code here`

Comment: ..Should we answer after the interview is over?

Comment: `B a = ...` would do it.

Comment: The best thing to do is to write the code and try many things in order to understand what really happens.

Comment: The good old "please read my mind" interview question!

Comment: Looks like a trick question.. Was there more space to explain ?

Comment: No way you can do this... Are you sure this was the question?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class B {
  void f1(){}   
}

public class A extends B {
  void f2(){}
}

void main(String[] args) {
  A a =  new A();
  a.f2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options

- Make your object a have a reference varible of B `B a = new B()` (ignore the naming violation ;))
- update the call of f2() and cast it to B
- Add f2() in A and then override it in B

Then if you call

```
A o = new B();
o.f2();
```

it will call the f2() in object B

There is nothing you can put in `<- free space here` to make it call f2() in B I am afraid. Perhaps a trick interview questions?

Answer (score 1):

i would do the following:

```
A a =  new B();
```

then cast it to B and call f2:

```
((B) a).f2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Only like this :)

```
void main(String[] args) {
  B a =  new B();
  a.f2();
}
```

Comment: Beeng in confusion, i've wrote 
     B b =  new B();
     b.f2();
but they said too much changes. Then I asked to change the name of the object to a, like u wrote, but guess that made them angry

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can achieve it using

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent p=new Child();
    ((Child)p).f2();
}
```

All changes only in the free space provided :)